# AutoMapper - Map Derived Class To Dto

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

Im trying to map a Class which inherits from a base class to a dto.

```
public class LaunchConfiguration : Document
{
     public string Brand { get; set; }
     public string SettingName{ get; set; }
}

public class LaunchConfigurationDto
{
     public string Brand { get; set; }
     public string SettingName{ get; set; }
}
```

The point of the dto is to hide the fields of the base document when it gets returned to the user. This is my Map configuration

```
public class DtoProfile : Profile
{
    public DtoProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<LaunchConfiguration,LaunchConfigurationDto>();
    }
};
```

The problem im having is that auto mapper complains about the base class properties which are not mapped . "Unmapped members were found." The properties are the ones on the base class. I have tried specifying this to be ignored in the profile to no avail . Can anyone specify the correct way to do this ?

My ConfigureServices Method incase anyone is wondering :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = Configuration["ApiInformation:Name"], Version = Configuration["ApiInformation:Version"] });
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
        });

        services.AddAutoMapper(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new DtoProfile());
        });
         services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        });
    }
```

My Base Class :

```
 public class Document : IDocument, IDocument<Guid>
{

public Document()
{
  this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
  this.AddedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
}

/// <summary>The Id of the document</summary>
[BsonId]
public Guid Id { get; set; }

/// <summary>The datetime in UTC at which the document was added.</summary>
public DateTime AddedAtUtc { get; set; }

/// <summary>The version of the schema of the document</summary>
public int Version { get; set; }
 }
```

My implementation where _mapper is my Injected mapper and _repo My Injected Repo. Exception Occurs on Map Method call

```
 Task ILaunchConfigurationService<LaunchConfigurationDto >.InsertLaunchConfiguration(LaunchConfigurationDto model)
    {
         var mapped =  _mapper.Map<LaunchConfiguration >(model);
        return _repo.AddOneAsync(mapped);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or regular .NET Framework? I tried your code in console app and got no error. But since Core and regular version differ it might be the cause.

Comment: .Net Core using AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: I literally copy pasted your code (except for Swagger part). When do you get the exception? During initialization phase or when you try to apply Map in the controller? Also can you provide a base class Document in the question?

Comment: Sure give me one second , I will update the original question.

Comment: Is it correct - you try to map LaunchConfigurationDto to LaunchConfiguration? 
Or is it just a typo?

Comment: Correct , I wish to hide the base class properties from the user once i return them from my api. They are part of the generic repository I have .

Comment: The same goes for adding as the user is not concerned with the `Id`,`AddedAtUtc` and `Version` fields

Comment: Next time try to give more detail straightaway, especially on code part where the exception was thrown - it faciliates locating the bug.

Comment: Are you trying to map Dto back to Entity? Don't do that **EVER**, especially not with ORMs such as EntityFramework. In 98% of all cases this won't work as expected. AutoMapper was made for easily mapping of Domain Entities to DTOs or ViewModels, not the other way around

Comment: @Tseng this is not the case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem should be solved by simply adding ReverseMap() to CreateMap call:

```
public class DtoProfile : Profile
{
    public DtoProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<LaunchConfiguration, LaunchConfigurationDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
};
```

Automapper creates one way map by default. ReverseMap is just a sugar for creating reverse map in case there are no peculiar mappings in one way. You could also do it like this:

```
public class DtoProfile : Profile
{
    public DtoProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<LaunchConfiguration, LaunchConfigurationDto>();
        CreateMap<LaunchConfigurationDto, LaunchConfiguration>();
    }
};
```

You can read more about this in [documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html)

However I cannot guarantee you that you will not experience exceptions from database with your current implementation on commiting changes.

Comment: Thank you very much , this indeed did the trick , wish I could up vote you publicly but my rep is too low.